# Matching as Pascal case or sentence case not both

Tags: c#, regex

I havbe some regex with is matching Pascal case and sentence case, however my regex for pascal case is also matching sentence case.

i.e. Pascal case should match "AllPascalCase" but not "Sentence case" and Sentence case should match "Sentence case" but not "AllPascalCase".

for the Pascal case regex I am using

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+$
```

for the sentence case regex I am using

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+([ -_]([a-z]+))+$
```

it looks like the sentence case is also matching Pascal case as well as sentence case.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The expression looks OK to me, are you sure you are calling it correctly from your code?

Comment: give an example for pascal case.

Comment: I've added the regex I am using for sentence case, here I expect to see a delimiter between each word, where the delimiter is either a space, hyphen or underscore

Comment: *Pascal case should match "AllPascalCase" but not "Sentence case"* - it already does?

Comment: Looks like my test was breaking on sentence case matching "PascalCase" not the other way. I've updated the question to reflect this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this Regex expression i hope it helps

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+([ _-]([a-z]+))+$
```

**hyphens and underscore positions are interchanged**

--SJ

Comment: Well spotted, `' ' to '_'` includes all the uppercase letters.